# Get value from JMeter variable like varName_1, varName_2 in a loop

Tags: jmeter

I'm getting multiple rows from database through JMeter. I need to construct a string using those values.

I have a for loop that iterates from 1 to varName_#. How do I evaluate the values of varName_1, varName_2 etc.

I tried using `${__V(varName_${i})}`, `${__eval(varName_${i})}`,`${__evalVar(varName_${i})}`

```
for(int i=1; i <= Integer.parseInt(vars.get("varName_#"); i++) { 
    myString.append(newline);
    myString.append("{");
    myString.append(newline);
    myString.append("\"id\" : ").append(${__V(varName_${i})}).append(",");
    myString.append(newline);
    myString.append("\"version\" : 0").append(",");
    myString.append(newline);
    myString.append("\"children\" : []");
    myString.append(newline);
    myString.append("}");

    if(i != Integer.parseInt(vars.get("varName_#")) {
        children.append(",");       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `vars` to get value in index i:

```
 vars.get("varName_" + i);
```

In your code:

```
 myString.append("\"id\" : ").append(vars.get("varName_" + i));
```